# ASP.net GridView is empty when going back or forward to it

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have a databound `asp:GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridUsers" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
   <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="UserGUID" HeaderText="UserGUID" SortExpression="UserGUID" Visible="False" />
       <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="UserGUID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~\UserManagement\UserProperties.aspx?userGuid={0}" DataTextField="Username" HeaderText="User name" SortExpression="Username" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Fullname" HeaderText="Full name" SortExpression="Fullname" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description"/>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="E-mail" SortExpression="Email"/>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="IsActive" HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="IsActive" Visible="False" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="AuthenticationType" HeaderText="Account type" SortExpression="AuthenticationType" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT UserGUID, Username, Fullname, Description, Email, IsActive, AuthenticationType FROM Users WHERE IsActive = 1 ORDER BY Username">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

With the corresponding code-behind:

```
public partial class FooItToHoo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

The grid populates correctly fine when i browse to the page:

But when i go **back** and then **forward** (or navigate to another page and go **back**) the grid is empty:

If i hit F5, the page refreshes, and the grid is present and populated:

What am i doing wrong?

---

**Update**: The initial request for my page is not cached; the response from the server is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Wed, 13 Jun 2012 13:16:32 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 53219
Connection: Close
```

With the `asp:GridView` content being rendered *in* the served html:

Navigating away and then going **Back**, no server request is made; so the page must be served from the cache.

What is ASP.net doing that the rendered page contains contents, but the "cached" page does not?

Comment: you are hitting a cache version of your page? trying clreaing your cache and re-running your test.

Answer (score 0):

The reason grid is showing as empty is because when you click on next button then there is no data source available to bind with grid. 
So for this you need to

select gridview -> goto properties window ->click on events button

double click on pageindexchanging event

and set

`Allowpaging=true` for gridview

in pageindex changing event write the following code

```
gridview1.pageindex=e.newpageindex;
//gridbindingcode

gridview1.databind();
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be cache problem. remove cache from your browser and use below code on your page to prevent your page from being caching.

The Meta tags:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" CONTENT="0">
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

And the code:

```
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now;
Response.Expires = -1441;
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-store");
Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
```